# Installing Google Tags Manager in Wordpress (without writing in the PHP theme)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to install Google Tags Manager on my WordPress site.
I've seen a few guides that teach how to go about it, but all of them require me to put a code in my theme's php (in the Appearance->editor) for the `<body>` code part.
The problem for me is that the guy who built my theme said that once an update would be released, 
the code I'd insert would be deleted.

Is there any other way to insert the codes google tags manager requires (especially after the `<body>`) - without doing so in the theme's php?

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: first of all, not using child theme is bad practice. the guys, who build your theme, should created child theme( if parent theme may be updated ). what to do : there are tone of plugins, which do the job -> just go to add plugin and insert google tag into search field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler way to do this is via a plugin, trying to insert random code pieces into your php theme might break the website.

You can install one of these easy to use plugins. And then insert the google tag code into the plugin. Try the free plugin in the link provided here. Download the plugin and then install into your wordpress site.

Ref: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duracelltomi-google-tag-manager/

If you are new to WordPress, try this tutorial on how to install a plugin. Please do note, You will need to have been an administrator user to install the plugin.

Ref:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/step-by-step-guide-to-install-a-wordpress-plugin-for-beginners/

Hope this helps...